# How to remove Dictionary Objects that have same value?

Tags: dictionary

```
Object o1 = new Object("username1", "password");
Object o2 = new Object("username2", "password");
Object o3 = new Object("username2", "password");
Dictionary<int, Object> d = new Dictionary<int, Object>();
d.Add(1, o1);
d.Add(2, o2);
d.Add(3, o3);`
```

---

o2 and o3 have the same value
I want to remove one programmatically.
My code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <d.Count; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < d.Count; j++)
     {
        if(d[i]==d[j])
          {
             d.Remove[i];
          }                   
     }
 }'
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I see various issues in these code snippets, which should be solved *before* any attempt to perform your actual task of deleting objects with the same value: 1) You seem to be (ab)using the dictionary key for an index, so you can iterate over the keys. If you just want a sequential list, use a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). 2) Your "indices" run from 1 to 3, but you iterate from 0 to 2. 3) You should show your code for your `Object` type. It could be `System.Object` (in which case already the constructor calls should fail), or it could ...

Comment: ... be a custom class named `Object` (in which case the comparison by `==` in your loop won't do what you think, and the choice of name might be questionable), or it might be a custom structure named `Object` (in which case we'd need to see your `==` overload, and the same applies for the name). 4) If you execute your loop as is, you won't be removing only duplicate values, you'll be removing *all* values because you're comparing each item to itself. 5) Your loop could work, but only once, because you do not fill in the gaps of the deleted indices/move up the following items. ...

Comment: ... 6) Your code looks like you might be storing passwords as plain text, which is a bad idea. 7) Generally, for this question and for future questions, "It doesn't work" is *not* a valid description of a problem. Please make sure to provide some information as detailed as possible, i.e. answer the following questions: What's the expected output? What's the actual output? Is there any error message? Is it a compilation error or a runtime error? What line and column does the error occur in? Thank you :)